# Vue3 v-for using pinia computed property not updating correctly

Tags: vuejs3, pinia

I have a component that fetches employees from a pinia store, and a filter component to filter employees by office.

When I inspect the data in Vue devtools, both `selectedOffices` and `filteredEmployeeList` looks as expected. But the list rendered in the component (filteredEmployeeList) doesn't match the data displayed in devtools.

Any ideas?

**Component**

```
<template>
<div class="employees">
  <EmployeeCard
    v-for="(employee, idx) in filteredEmployeeList"
    :key="idx"
    :employee-data="employee"
  />
</div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia';
import EmployeeFilter from '@/components/EmployeeFilter.vue';
import EmployeeCard from '@/components/EmployeeCard.vue';

import { useEmployeesStore } from '@/stores/employees';
const employeesStore = useEmployeesStore();
const { filteredEmployeeList } = storeToRefs(employeesStore);

</script>
```

**Filter component**

```
<div class="filter-wrapper">
      <div 
        v-for="(office, idx) in employeesStore.offices" 
        class="office-filter"
      >
        <label :for="idx">
          <input 
            v-model="employeesStore.selectedOffices"
            :value="office"
            class="checkbox"
            type="checkbox"
          >
            {{ office }}
        </label>
      </div>
</div>
```

**Store**

```
const selectedOffices = ref([]);

const selectedFiltersLength = computed(() => {
    return selectedOffices.value.length;
  });

const filteredEmployeeList = computed(() => {
   // No filters selected, return all employees 
   if (selectedFiltersLength.value == 0) {
      return employees.value;
    }

    return employees.value.filter(employee => selectedOffices.value.includes(employee.office));
  });
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWs31.png)

Comment: You have a ID in you employee? I believe the problem it's with the idx, try this <EmployeeCard
      v-for="employee in filteredEmployeeList"
      :key="employee.id"
      :employee-data="employee"
    />

Comment: Could you provide a *runnable* [mcve]? Use codesandbox or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, found the problem. It was as you said, problem with the :key attribute. Changed to employee.id and it works like a charm.